# How to extract the string from this attribute in HTML?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this line of python code:

```
print(soup.find_all("tr")[1].find_all("td")[2])
```

And it gives me this string of HTML:

```
<td class="description" classname="description" data-track-string="ls_24_hour_ls_24_hour_toggle" headers="description" title="Some clouds. Low 27F. Winds SE at 5 to 10 mph."><span>Partly Cloudy</span></td>
```

Now I want to print only the text that is set equal to "title".

For example,

In title="Some clouds. Low 27F. Winds SE at 5 to 10 mph.", I simply want the terminal to display the string of text "Some clouds. Low 27F. Winds SE at 5 to 10 mph."

How would I go about achieving this?

Sorry if this is a rudimentary question, but I haven't found anything that helps with my specific issue. Thank you.

Comment: `print(soup.find_all("tr")[1].find_all("td")[2]['title'])`?

Comment: Wow, that's exactly it. Thank you!

Comment: Are there more elements with the attribute data-track-string="ls_24_hour_ls_24_hour_toggle? Or is this the only one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple string manipulation.

```
a = '<td class="description" classname="description" data-track-string="ls_24_hour_ls_24_hour_toggle" headers="description" title="Some clouds. Low 27F. Winds SE at 5 to 10 mph."><span>Partly Cloudy</span></td>'
count = len("title=")
b = a.find("title=")
c = a.find('><span>')
d = a[b+count:c]
print (d)
```

Or you can use also `regex`.